# Do I have to vote 3 times?

Tags: support, election

Do you have to vote in an election for 3 candidates to have your votes counted?

Because I'm only voting for 2 candidates, will my vote be counted at all?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No you don't have to vote three times.

If there are any candidates you don't want to vote for just use your 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> choice votes as appropriate.